# aliased union in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

In sqlalchemy I am trying to union tables and then make alias with `WHERE` and `ORDER_BY`

something like

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT [TABLE_ONE].[SOME_ID] AS [SOME_ID]
  FROM [TABLE_ONE] 
  UNION 
  SELECT [TABLE_TWO].[SOME_ID] AS [SOME_ID]
  FROM [TABLE_TWO]
) AS anon_1
WHERE ...
```

SQLAlchemy:

```
select_q = select([TABLE_ONE.c.SOME_ID], TABLE_ONE)
select_w = select([TABLE_TWO.c.SOME_ID], TABLE_TWO)
union_qw = union(select_q,select_w) 
union_qw_aliased = aliased(union_qw)
s = select('*',union_qw_aliased)
```

but SQLAlchemy produces SQL code:

```
SELECT anon_1.[SOME_ID]
FROM (SELECT [TABLE_ONE].[SOME_ID] AS [SOME_ID]
FROM [TABLE_ONE] UNION SELECT [TABLE_TWO].[SOME_ID] AS [SOME_ID]
FROM [TABLE_TWO]) AS anon_1
WHERE SELECT [TABLE_ONE].[SOME_ID]
FROM [TABLE_ONE] UNION SELECT [TABLE_TWO].[SOME_ID]
FROM [TABLE_TWO]
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're mis-using the second argument to "select()", which is actually the "whereclause" (though we encourage the use of the `where()` method these days).  the FROM clause is usually implicit from the columns you're selecting.  For your "select *", we can set an explicit FROM using `select_from()`:

```
from sqlalchemy import *

m = MetaData()
t1 = Table('t1', m, Column('id', Integer))
t2 = Table('t2', m, Column('id', Integer))

select_q = select([t1])
select_w = select([t2])
union_qw = union(select_q, select_w)
union_qw_aliased = union_qw.alias()
s = select('*').select_from(union_qw_aliased)

print s
```

output:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT t1.id AS id 
FROM t1 UNION SELECT t2.id AS id 
FROM t2) AS anon_1
```

to do more WHERE, add that using `where()` and do it against union_qw_aliased:

```
print s.where(union_qw_aliased.c.id == 5)
```

output:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT t1.id AS id 
FROM t1 UNION SELECT t2.id AS id 
FROM t2) AS anon_1 
WHERE anon_1.id = :id_1
```